# How to test whether a matrix is empty

Tags: r, matrix

I created an empty matrix by `matrix()`, when I need to test whether a given matrix is empty, How can I do that? I know that `is.na(matrix())` is `TRUE`, but if given matrix is higher dimension, it cannot determine.

What I mean empty is element full of `NA` or `NULL`.

Comment: `all(is.na(yourmatrix))`?

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example of an empty matrix. A matrix can't be "full of NULL".

Comment: you need to be more exact in your question. particularly, is `matrix(NaN)` "empty" for your purpose. or what about `matrix("")`. the first case is caught by `all(is.na(...))` but not the second. or is `matrix(list(NULL))` "a matrix full of NULL" as you put it? if yes then you need something more complicated to catch it. `all(apply(matrix(list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), nrow=2), 1:2, function(x) length(x[[1]]))==0)`

Comment: @lebatsnok, for your (unlikely) `NULL` example, couldn't you just do `is.null(unlist(M))` if "M" was `matrix(list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), nrow = 2)`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you are just looking for `all`. Here's a small example:

```
M1 <- matrix(NA, ncol = 3, nrow = 3)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA
M2 <- matrix(c(1, rep(NA, 8)), ncol = 3, nrow = 3)
M2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA

all(is.na(M1))
# [1] TRUE
all(is.na(M2))
# [1] FALSE
```